# How to add PHP on Javascript code

Tags: javascript, php

i want to make dynamic button with javascript.. 
i dont know how to combination php with js .

this code, i want to make number 12 to be dynamic 13..14..15 etc but it call from php ..

```
<input type="button" class="btn_12" value="Klik Button"/>


<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    $(".btn_12").click(function(){
        $(".field12").toggle();  
    }); 
});
</script>
```

May you know how to add a php on js ? Thanks so much before

Comment: Please clarify your question. As it stands, it's hardly understandable.

Comment: You can send/receive data by ajax query to server.

Comment: You mean like `class="btn_<?php echo '12'; ?>"`

Comment: Do you want to create a loop that outputs multiple buttons with associated JavaScript for each button?

Comment: First you need to make this distinction. PHP runs on the server, while JS runs on the client (browser). So once JS is running there is no more PHP code, just the generated HTML.

Comment: anyway thanks all .. @SurrealDreams answered it , i'm just not careful -___- good night :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible to output JavaScript with PHP, much like you can output HTML.  It's really no different.  Let's say your PHP has the value you want to output stored in $number:

```
<input type="button" class="btn_<?php echo $number; ?>" value="Tafsir Jalalain"/>


<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    $(".btn_<?php echo $number; ?>").click(function(){
        $(".field<?php echo $number; ?>").toggle();  
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Your output HTML and JavaScript will now all use the value from $number, whatever that is.  **Please note** - this will output a $number into your page, **ONCE**.  The value injected into your page will not change once the page is loaded.  If you need to dynamically change the content of the HTML without reloading the page, you'll need to look into AJAX.

Comment: yes, i was do it before but it can't

Comment: @tara - Sorry, I'm not sure what your comment means.

Comment: @tara But this is the way it works. Is php installed on your server?

Comment: i just try it .. but it can't work ..

Comment: @tara - What does "it can't work" mean?

Comment: aaaaah .. thanks i'm not careful , i'm missing coma after echo -____-

Comment: so sorry my question it just simple.. but i dont know really about js with php .. thanks @SurrealDreams

Comment: thanks too for @j08691

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a better way to solve your javascript problem. Rather than have a separate javascript function for each button, you could give all the buttons a common class, and give each button a data attribute for the field it should toggle. Then you can attach the handler to the common class, and check the data attribute to determine which field to toggle inside the handler. For example:

```
<?php foreach ($item as $number): ?>
  <input type='button' class='btn toggle' data-toggle='<?php echo $number; ?>' value='Tafsir Jalalain' />
<?php endforeach; ?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function() {
    fieldnum = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
    $('.field' + fieldnum).toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```